# How to set hidden element id first with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some trouble when hide first the id with jquery. i already set $("#before-show").hide(); but it still looking after reloading, and then hide.

here my trying example code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#before-show").hide();
  $("#show").on('click', function() {
    $(".box").fadeIn();
    $(".button-show").fadeOut();
  });
  $("#hide").on('click', function() {
    $(".box").fadeOut();
    $(".button-show").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show" class="button-show">
  <button>show</button>
</div>

<div id="before-show" class="box">
  <div class="hello">
    <button id="hide">hide</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

it's work but have problem after reloading browser still looking 3 seconds and after that hide. Is that anyway to asynchronus function hide() ?

Note : Don't use css, because i not put id in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply hide it using CSS instead of JavaScript.

```
#before-show { display: none; }
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#show").on('click', function() {
    $(".box").fadeIn();
    $(".button-show").fadeOut();
  });
  $("#hide").on('click', function() {
    $(".box").fadeOut();
    $(".button-show").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
#before-show { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show" class="button-show">
  <button>show</button>
</div>

<div id="before-show" class="box">
  <div class="hello">
    <button id="hide">hide</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: only with jquery bro, with css it work but i not put id in css

Comment: Then why tag CSS? And what is the rule - no CSS at all? No ID rules? No external CSS? What if the jQuery created the CSS rule? What if you used a class or element selector instead? You really need to clarify. This seems like a very large caveat to omit from your question.

Comment: You're at the mercy of page load if you use JavaScript to do the job of CSS. Without knowing the actual reasons or rules behind avoiding CSS IDs, you're not going to get a good answer unfortunately.

Comment: my reason not use id in css is for A consistent convention bro

Comment: Then add `class="hidden"` to the div and put `.hidden { display: none; }` in your CSS instead. But more importantly, if your convention is actively harming site performance, then perhaps it's time to rethink that convention...

Comment: but if not there anyway using javascript, i will use in css :), i only want to research it

Answer (score 0):

If you want the element to be hidden on page load, you should hide it in css, not in javascript because the page is rendered before the javascript is run. Try this:

```
<style>
#before-show
{
   display: none
}
</style>
```

Comment: so there is no otherway to use javascript?

Answer (score 0):

html run line by line 
generally html run fast, but you import jquery use other website, you can check how match time it used by F12->network , maybe this bring your question

moreover,

i suggest that you can set the div hidden use css first : display : none

Comment: While this may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can have the element that you want to start off hidden as:

```
<div id="before-show" class="box" style="display: none;">
  <div class="hello">
    <button id="hide">hide</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then after that, you can set it's ID before making it visible as:

```
$('box')
.css("display", "block")
.attr('id', 'someId');
```

Good luck.

Comment: i already try again but, it's still looking in 3 seconds. is that causes in my network?

Comment: I cannot imagine how it would be still visible if you set it to be display: none from the start.